# jQuery calendar integration with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

I want to integrate calendar which can display full calendar but start must be user defined like e.g.July'13 - June'14.

And which can allow add events on day wise not time wise for specific day. So event should be for whole day. Calendar can have various symbols for specific events. In short I need symbolic calendar.

Please suggest such jQuery plug in which can be helpful for me.

Thanks.

Comment: your solution needs more than just javascript. You need to store your events on the server side some how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this calendar plugin As It provides monthly, weekly and daily event management as well as some good jquery concepts are implemented with this plugin.

[see here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)